# Implications using inequality signs <= and <

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, inequality

Suppose we have a *theorem* that says: If  $A \le X \le B$ and $A$, $B$ both have property $p$ then $X$ has property $p$.

I'm working on some problem and I derive that $A < X < B$ and $A$, $B$ both have property $p$. Can I use *the theorem* to conclude that $X$ has property $p$?

Comment: $A<X<B$ implies that $A\leq X\leq B$ and then you're fine using your theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

> $A < X$

then we can conclude

> $A < X$ or $A = X$

and thus

> $A \leq X$